# Replacement for FCM diagnostic

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In order to troubleshoot notifications delivery we used **FCM diagnostics** as recommended at:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en

But now I see:

> FCM diagnostics page to be removed
>
> From Nov 20 2017, the FCM diagnostics page will be removed along with any historical data. However, you can continue to access other Firebase Cloud Messaging features on the Play Console.

What is an alternative to track delivery problem per `message_id`? I can't believe they would like to troubleshoot our issue in support tickets...

Comment: Spotted your comment on Google groups, although they obviously didn't advise availability. We are also totally in the dark without some sort of diagnostic facility, mainly when the device hasn't received the notification (fine when it does because it responds). FCM Diagnostics was pretty archaic and could've done with improvement, so let's hope that's an api coming soon in Firebase.

Comment: @rangi One of indirect API is useful: `curl --header 'Authorization: key=XXXXXX' https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/YYYYYY?details=true` https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server - there is date when phone last time pull FCM notifications... At least that spots some connectivity issues...

Comment: Thanks @gavenkoa and I use that api. Just to clarify, it returns something like this: {"applicationVersion":"9","connectDate":"2017-11-23","attestStatus":"NOT_ROOTED","application":"com.xxx.yyy.i.o.t","scope"
:"*","authorizedEntity":"265477554391","rel":{"topics":{"9123489580":{"addDate":"2017-06-25"},"50508080":{"addDate":"2017-11-21"}}},"connectionT
ype":"WIFI","appSigner":"15df840d8bfc40d8bfc40d8bfc40d8bfc9a2e37a18","platform":"ANDROID"}

Comment: Also got response from Firebase: "I understand that FCM Diagnostics was critical to you in troubleshooting FCM messages but unfortunately this has been deprecated.
Rest assured that we are working on something better that should allow a lot more insight into what went wrong during message delivery, but we can’t share any timelines. I’ll share your concern internally and continue to work to get this new feature out. ツ"

Comment: **@rangi** Yes, `connectDate` attribute provides some inside about what happened on app side.

Comment: cant believe Google did this, removing useful tool without new solution coming in.